# Lejos - Cannot find Symbol Tachopilot

Tags: java, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

Currently attempting to get some code to compile using Lejos for the Lego NXT brick. The command I run is `nxjc Nxt_code.java` and I get a Cannot find symbol error. TachoPilot has been imported. Here is the output from the console:

```
`Nxt_code.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TachoPilot
location: package lejos.robotics.navigation
import lejos.robotics.navigation.TachoPilot;
                            ^
Nxt_code.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TachoPilot
location: class NXT.Nxt_code
private TachoPilot pilot;
        ^
Nxt_code.java:313: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TachoPilot
location: class NXT.Nxt_code
public Nxt_code(TachoPilot pilot) {
                ^
Nxt_code.java:56: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TachoPilot
location: class NXT.Nxt_code
    TachoPilot pilot = new TachoPilot(WHEEL_DIAMETER, TRACK_WIDTH, Motor.B,
    ^
Nxt_code.java:56: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TachoPilot
location: class NXT.Nxt_code
    TachoPilot pilot = new TachoPilot(WHEEL_DIAMETER, TRACK_WIDTH, Motor.B,
                           ^
5 errors
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: We're using Lejos 0.9.0 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in 0.9b; not sure about 0.8.5, but it's in 0.8.

I've seen a few impls, or copying it from 0.8 might work (with any tweaks necessary).

Comment: It is now called LegacyPilot and the docs recommend you use a MoveContoller instead so I used DifferentialPilot

Comment: @silleknarf Ah; good to know--I skipped a few versions, which probably helped ;)